# Hat dash doesn't work on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I got a notification saying

> You earned the right to run fast and jump for joy on Winter Bash!

But it requires a spacebar, which I don't have available on mobile. Nor do I have a cantina.

I noticed this in desktop mode.

Here is a video of my struggles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzrQf.jpg

Can we get this available on mobile?

Comment: ([this](https://d13ezvd6yrslxm.cloudfront.net/wp/wp-content/images/ZZ4051C5AB.jpg) is what I mean by cantina)

Comment: It is working with touch screen for me when tapping..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I just realized I did this on desktop mode

Comment: Close: [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** Hat Dash should now be working properly on mobile devices, both in regular (mobile) mode and desktop mode.

---

It works for me on my phone and on desktop (in mobile test mode) - tapping the screen should be the equivalent of a space. Still need to make the modal fit better, but you should be able to play.

> dash around the hats
> on desktop use your space bar
> mobile: tap finger

Comment: I've edited in a video of it not working, into my question

Comment: what mobile browser?

Comment: Chrome 87.0.4280.101 I think?

Comment: Are you in desktop mode or regular mobile mode? (From the looks of it, it looks like desktop mode).

Comment: I'm in desk top mode (mainly as the snowflake menu item didn't appear on the mobile nav bar)

Comment: @Pureferret should be working now, please confirm

Comment: Its working now