# No Hat Dash Button

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I just realized I should see a "Hat Dash" button on winterbash home page when logged in:

[image]

However, no such button for me:

[image: no hat dash button]

Can I please get the button too?

Comment: It seems that you have to [earn that right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357934/643262). That's all I know...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Part of the fun is to figure out how to earn the privilege to jump for joy and keep your (social) distance from the obstacles.

> different ways to play
> how is the button unlocked?
> one way to find out