# Why didn't I get a "Jump for Joy" notification this morning?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020

To earn the right to play the Hat Dash game, you need to first get the "Jump for Joy" notification:

[image]

I didn't get this notification in my inbox or Winter-bash drop-down (first notification I got was for a Social Distancing hat).

Why didn't I get/earn this notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yaakov confirmed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357996/369802) that this is some sort of hidden 'privilege' that needs to be earned. Maybe there's even a clue in there: There are a few hats related to social distancing. Did you try wearing one yet?

The definite clue for unlocking it will probably be added to the list [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/369802) when people figure it out :)

Comment: Got it.  Finally.  Thanks for the clues!

Comment: @Snow Enjoy the loss of productivity!