# Where can I find the leaderboard for Winter Bash 2020?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Where can I find the leaderboard for [Winter Bash 2020](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Here: https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the leaderboard **in number of hats**, visit https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard. You can see the leaderboard of who has earned the most hats (and which hats they've earned) for the network or individual sites, and which sites have earned the most hats.

[image: screenshot of the hats leaderboard]

For the leaderboard for **the running game**, visit https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard. This will give you statistics about people's games and high scores, including who has <s>wasted</s> spent the most time playing.

[image: screenshot of the hat dash leaderboard]

Comment: Wait what game is this?

Comment: @CinCout - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357999/294691

Comment: Whoa! I have a lot of hats, but no notification :(

Comment: Got the right to run fast and jump for joy :P

Comment: and as individual per side the leaderboard?